# Visual Studio 2010 says "File '//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js' could not be found"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, warnings

In Visual Studio 2010, in the .cshtml file I have the following script element:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js"></script>
```

It's underlined in green and giving me the warning "File '//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js' could not be found".

I can browse to `//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js` though so it definitely **does** exist.

My Target Schema for Validation is `HTML5`.

Why is it complaining about this and how can I stop it?

Comment: This is only a warning, correct? It shouldn't really matter. The IDE probably thinks it's supposed to be a relative path, but can't find it locally.

Comment: Just because your browser is smart enough to second-guess the protcol ("http:"), doesn't mean MSVS doesn't need it!!!!  Try this: `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the protocol in front:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js"></script>
```

Browsers will automatically correct the URL when you enter it in the address bar, but when using it in the source of the page it will default to a local file...which is wrong in this case.